# Undefined reference to std::__cxx11:: errors (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, bash, ubuntu

Windows 10 Anniversary Update came out a couple of months ago, and I'm trying out the new "**Bash on Ubuntu on Windows**" feature.

I used it to compile some of my previous projects (finished on a normal Ubuntu machine), and while most of them were successfully built, a few of them received multiple `undefined reference to ... (std::__cxx11::...`  errors when **building the entire project** (after compilations on separate files are done without errors).

I tried switching to g++-4.8, g++-4.9, g++-5.4 and g++-6.2 and all of them came down to the same result. I also tried adding compiler option `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`/`-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` in *Makefile* and still ended up with the same errors.

Here are parts of these error messages:

```
> building cirTest...
../../lib/libcmd.a(cmdCommon.o): In function `HistoryCmd::exec(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `myStr2Int(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int&)'
../../lib/libcmd.a(cmdCommon.o): In function `HelpCmd::exec(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0x91d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
../../lib/libcmd.a(cmdCommon.o): In function `UsageCmd::exec(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0xd5c): undefined reference to `myStrNCmp(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0xdb9): undefined reference to `myStrNCmp(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0xe68): undefined reference to `myStrNCmp(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
../../lib/libcmd.a(cmdCommon.o): In function `QuitCmd::exec(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0x1190): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_not_of(char, unsigned long) const'
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0x126f): undefined reference to `myStrNCmp(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
cmdCommon.cpp:(.text+0x1320): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

Since most of my projects did build successfully, I wonder if it's possible to solve the problem by toggling some settings without jumping to the conclusion that this is simply a result of "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" still being a "beta" feature.

Comment: How does your compiler command line look like?

Comment: Looks like you are compiling for C++11 but your runtime library does not support it.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd --version` ? I've upgraded my wsl to Ubuntu 16.04 so I don't remember the default value